# chrome suddenly not wrapping inline-block inside table

Tags: html, css

I've got a table that hasn't changed in years.  However the latest version of Chrome no longer renders it properly.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/36pearxL/

```
.OrderDetailsTable {
width:1000px;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.OrderDetailsTable .photoHolder {
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}
.OrderDetailsTable .photoHolder .photoNumber {
background-color:#fff;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
padding:2px;
font-weight:bold;
}


<table class="OrderDetailsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td class="field">Use MLS Photo</td>
      <td>
        <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>1</span><img src='1.jpg' alt='1' width='200' height='200' /></span>&nbsp;
        <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>2</span><img src='2.jpg' alt='2' width='200' height='200' /></span>&nbsp;
        <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>3</span><img src='3.jpg' alt='3' width='200' height='200' /></span>&nbsp;
        <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>4</span><img src='4.jpg' alt='4' width='200' height='200' /></span>&nbsp;
        <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>5</span><img src='5.jpg' alt='5' width='200' height='200' /></span>&nbsp;
        <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>6</span><img src='6.jpg' alt='6' width='200' height='200' /></span>&nbsp;
        <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>7</span><img src='7.jpg' alt='7' width='200' height='200' /></span>&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

The table has a width of 1000px set in css but no column widths, and the images are wrapped in spans that are set to display:inline-block.  In Firefox, Edge, IE, and old versions of Chrome this means the table's columns are automatically set to approximately 156px for the first column and 843px for the second. With a 1px border between them for a total of 1000px wide.

In the current version of Chrome the 2nd column doesn't wrap at all and the table expands past 1000px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the same issue just an hour ago (Chrome 76.0.3809.132 64-bit). It seems to be related to the non-breaking space (nbsp;)

```
<td>
    <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>1</span><img src='1.jpg' alt='1' width='200' height='200' /></span>
    <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>2</span><img src='2.jpg' alt='2' width='200' height='200' /></span>
    <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>3</span><img src='3.jpg' alt='3' width='200' height='200' /></span>
    <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>4</span><img src='4.jpg' alt='4' width='200' height='200' /></span>
    <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>5</span><img src='5.jpg' alt='5' width='200' height='200' /></span>
    <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>6</span><img src='6.jpg' alt='6' width='200' height='200' /></span>
    <span class='photoHolder'><span class='photoNumber'>7</span><img src='7.jpg' alt='7' width='200' height='200' /></span>
  </td>
```

Should work as expected, although the reason behind the change in behavior is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the issue in our environment is fixed by adding the below display option:

***display: -webkit-inline-box;***

e.g.

```
.OrderDetailsTable .photoHolder {
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

Regards, Aravind